# JS variable not working in AJAX success

Tags: javascript, ajax

Fetched data from database with php and ajax, Everything is ok except note variable is empty.Can somebody find out the issue why note value is not going to display. How can i fix it.

```
success: function(response) {

var cats = {};
response.results.forEach(function(element) {
    cats[element.team] = cats[element.team] || [];
    cats[element.team].push(element);
});

var i = 0;

Object.keys(cats).forEach(function(team) {
    let html = '';

    // Append the category header
    html = '<tr>';
    html += '<td>' + team + '</td>';
    html += '</tr>';
    $('table').append(html);

    // Loop through the results for this category
    cats[team].forEach(function(element) {
        var id = element.id;
        var teamId = element.team_id;
        var names = element.player;
        var result = element.result;
        var note = element.note;

        html = '<tr>';
        html += '<input type="hidden" name="Id[]" value="' + id + '"/>';
        html += '<input type="hidden" name="data[' + i + '][team_id]" value="' + teamId + '"/>';
        html += '<td>' + names + '</td>';
        html += '<td><input type="text" name="result[]" value="' + result + '"></td>';
        html += '</tr>';
        $('table').append(html);
    });

    // Append the textarea at the end of the results
    html = '<tr>';
    html += '<td><textarea placeholder="note..." name="data[' + i + '][Note]">' + note + '</textarea></td>';
    html += '</tr>';
    $('table').append(html);
    i++;
});

}
```

**This is the output**

[image]

**database table**

[image]

**JSON output**

```
{"groupData":{"id":"23","group_name":"Group B"},"results": 
[{"id":"2","team_id":"4","team":"Team 
B","player":"Deno","result":"14","note":"Lost"}, 
{"id":"3","team_id":"4","team":"Team 
B","player":"Niob","result":"26","note":"Lost"}, 
{"id":"4","team_id":"4","team":"Team 
B","player":"Skion","result":"76","note":"lost"}, 
{"id":"5","team_id":"5","team":"Team 
C","player":"Bela","result":"47","note":"won"}, 
{"id":"6","team_id":"5","team":"Team 
C","player":"yomi","result":"57","note":"won"}]}
```

Comment: @Paulpro empty result

Comment: so then actually the whole of "element" is not populated? That must mean all your other fields like element.team_id are also failing. Are you getting console errors about undefined variables? What you've just reported there doesn't correlate with what you said in the question. Make sure you placed that console.log command within your cats[team].forEach loop.

Comment: You put a wrong place for note value. Check your code again and you will see mistake :))

Comment: Also, when you come to use the note variable in your HTML, you placed it _outside_ the foreach loop. So it's out of scope. It no longer exists. You probably have errors about undefined variables coming from that as well if you look in your console. Even if it did exist at that moment, which of the instances of `element` would it be coming from? Do you actually need to move that code for creating the HTML inside the foreach loop? It's hard to be sure because we can't see your data and we don't know what output you want to achieve. You didn't give us enough detail to answer the question fully.

Comment: @Tomato32 where should i place note value.

Comment: Sorry but with the code as shown it's impossible that you don't have errors about undefined variables (unless there's another variable also called `note` defined in a higher scope which you haven't shown here). Do you understand how to check your browser's console? Open the Developer Tools (press F12 on most browsers, or find it in the menu) and then look in the Console tab.

Comment: @SamDasti: As I see, you may have many notes data. Which note value do you want, the last note, right?

Comment: sorry!  it shows undefined variable error for `note`.

Comment: @ADyson i have added the output.

Comment: Can you console.log(note) right after var notes = ....?

Comment: Thankyou. But what about input JSON data as I also requested? That's more important actually.

Comment: Anyway, if note is a property of element, which represents a team member, then logically you would need one text area for each team member, whereas now you only have one per team. But maybe note is not really a property of a team member? We don't know because you didn't post the data I requested.

Comment: @ADyson you are right every team member have a note value, And all team members have same note, thats why i want 1 textarea for a whole team.

Comment: "every team member have a note value, And all team members have same note"...so then what is the point of having separate fields for them all, if they always all the same? Just make the note a property of team instead. If what you're saying is true then your data structure is not logical.

Comment: @SamDasti what is that data and where's it from? It's not valid JSON. That did not come directly from your Network tools. And it's still only the player data and not the team data. I asked for the whole response so we could understand the overall structure. It's really not very complicated to do so! If you can't manage looking in the response properly, then another option is to write `console.log(JSON.stringify(response);` just after the `success: function(response) {` line, and then look in the console to see it.

Comment: Anyway it's probably irrelevant now since you finally admitted that note is part of the Player record, when clearly from a logical point of view it should be part of the Team record. You're storing the same value repeatedly and it makes no sense to do so. Now finally it's giving you a problem when making your form because the data is in the wrong place. "Won" or "Lost" status belongs to the whole team. A single player cannot win or lose alone. Actually it really should belong to a specific match played by that team, but that's another story entirely. I advise you to alter your data structure.

Comment: @ADyson I have updated the question with the result of `console.log(JSON.stringify(response));` .

Comment: Ok that's better, thanks. Although it doesn't match your screenshot. Team A is missing. You could at least try to create consistent examples. It feels like your process is very disorganised. But like I said already, the solution is to modify your data structure. This "won/lost" data belongs to the team (or really, to a specific match played by that team, if you record such a thing), not to the individual players.

Comment: @ADyson these teams belongs to  groups, group 1 have team A, group 2 have team B and Team C. you can see the group id in the table,i have a separate table for groups. And on the group page every group have a button to display.

Comment: you've called your table "teams" but actually it holds players, not teams at all. You need a table for groups, a table for teams and then a table for the players in each team. That just records the setup. Then to get a real proper structure for this kind of thing you'd need a table for matches which would contain the IDs of each team who played a match and what the result was. Then you can also have a sub-table which records the IDs of the players who appeared for each team in a particular match. In summary, your data structure is massively over-simplified and inadequate for its purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set note value infront of cats[team].forEach(function(element) {}). Hope to help, my friend :))

```
    success: function(response) {

var cats = {};
response.results.forEach(function(element) {
    cats[element.team] = cats[element.team] || [];
    cats[element.team].push(element);
});

var i = 0;

Object.keys(cats).forEach(function(team) {
    let html = '';

    // Append the category header
    html = '<tr>';
    html += '<td>' + team + '</td>';
    html += '</tr>';
    $('table').append(html);

    var note;
    // Loop through the results for this category
    cats[team].forEach(function(element) {
        var id = element.id;
        var teamId = element.team_id;
        var names = element.player;
        var result = element.result;
        note = element.note;

        html = '<tr>';
        html += '<input type="hidden" name="Id[]" value="' + id + '"/>';
        html += '<input type="hidden" name="data[' + i + '][team_id]" value="' + teamId + '"/>';
        html += '<td>' + names + '</td>';
        html += '<td><input type="text" name="result[]" value="' + result + '"></td>';
        html += '</tr>';
        $('table').append(html);
    });

    // Append the textarea at the end of the results
    html = '<tr>';
    html += '<td><textarea placeholder="note..." name="data[' + i + '][Note]">' + note + '</textarea></td>';
    html += '</tr>';
    $('table').append(html);
    i++;
});

}
```

Comment: This is based on an assumption about the data structure, but SamDasti has not provided any information about the data.

Comment: @SamDasti again, please show your data so we can understand where the note property is actually held. I'm not asking for anything complicated, and it's vital to solving the problem, yet you are commenting on this instead of providing it.

Comment: @ADyson do you mean database table.

Comment: No. Read my last 2 comments on the main thread. We need to see the JSON data you're using - since that's the data which your JavaScript is trying to read. It isn't trying to read from the database tables directly. Again look in your developer console, go to the Network tab, find your AJAX request, click on it to open it, and go to the Response tab. There you'll see the JSON provided by the server.

Comment: @ADyson This is the result `[{id: "2", team_id: "4", team: "Team B", player: "Deno", result: "14", note: "Lost"},…]`

Comment: @SamDasti that is the result of only one player entry. Where is the rest including the teams etc? And please add it to the question, not here. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson Please have a look at the question now.

Comment: @SamDasti: See updated my answer. I think it's Ok now :))

Comment: @SamDasti: Well played, my friend. Sorry about the first answer :D